# Get auto height of a div without cloning it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element whose auto height, lets say, is 300px.
On a button click, I set it's height to 500px.
I would like to animate it's height back to its default height.
The only solution I know is to clone the div, store its height and use it accordingly.
A [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nLtVz/)

```
var elem = $("div").clone().height("auto").appendTo("body");
$('div').animate({"height": elem.height()});
elem.remove();
```

Is there a better way to do it? I dont want to clone as I have huge number of elements on my actual page.

Update:
I have created [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUL9H/). How would you get default height of element if its not yet set on load?

Comment: Can't you set the height to auto?

Comment: If I set height auto, there wont be any animation. I should set height only thru animation.

Comment: I recommend Chris's answer then

Answer (score 1):

you could store the height of the original when you set it's height to a static value, perhaps as a data attribute of the element.
so:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').data('origHeight',$('div').height());
    //Your code to set the height
});
```

then:

```
$('div').animate({"height": $('div').data('origHeight')});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about save "old height" to some attribute?

like this.

```
$('#someDiv').attr('old-height',$('#someDiv').height());
```

what do you say?